# image loading by classic ASP page is not cached

Tags: iis, asp-classic, http-caching

I'd like to hide my image, so I load images using ASP script. But I see the images are not cached, is there a way to cache this kind of images?

My code:

```
Response.Buffer = True
response.Expires=240
response.CacheControl="Public"
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.open "GET","http://www.test.net/images/" & request.querystring("ID"), False
http.Send
Response.BinaryWrite http.ResponseBody
Set http = Nothing
Response.Flush
Response.End
```

This file is named test.asp and I call it via test.asp?ID=12345, like that:

```
<img src="test.asp?ID=12345">
```

The firebug shows OK for the image to be loaded not 302 not modified.

Is it possible to cache such kind of images?

Comment: remember to unmark the [Disable Browser Cache](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nRNrE.png) option during the tests.

Comment: It is unmarked, so the cache is enabled. On static images it shows "304 - Not modified"

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason that ASP page can not be cached, since browser does not know which server side technology generated it. You only need to set proper HTTP header directives. In your case, at the minumum, you need to set Max-Age in the Cache Control directive, for example:

```
response.CacheControl="public, max-age=68400"
```

See following [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en) for other useful directives for HTTP case.

Comment: ASP page yes, but I am using ASP as a img src.

Comment: Why that matters? I have used similar code in PHP, Asp.NET, Java Servlets, JSP Pages.

Comment: The NET option in Firebug shows response 200 OK, so it means it is not cached ;-(